# How Webpack processes require('module') in source files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I see in the bundle output `.js` file for frontend part of my app there are `require('path')` and some other `require(<something>)`. I don't think I need `path` module and others that are more for server stuff, rather than client side.

I wonder, if it's normal when output files contain 'require()' calls or should Webpack convert them somehow?

Comment: Basically webpack converts them.

Comment: Why could it happen that it didn't convert some of them? I see just about 3-4 of these for not so simple application so I suppose others were converted and these weren't.

Comment: Did you use the correct loaders for your require statements?

Comment: I think so, I only use ts-loader to load typescript files.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also really new to Webpack even though I've never encountered your problem. But according to webpacks documentation you have to specify every loader of those files you're going to import through `import`or `require`. Maybe you're really missing something? Hopefully someone else will be able to help you after all.